# List add function isn't performing correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arraylist

My code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BattleCore : MonoBehaviour {

public List<GameObject> Enemy = new List<GameObject> ();
public List<EnemyFollow1> EnemyScript =  new List<EnemyFollow1>();
public List<StatData> stat = new List<StatData> ();
public int length;
public bool canMelee = false;
public List<ParticleSystem> ps = new List<ParticleSystem> (); 
public float AttackCooldownT = 0;
public float AttackCooldownTI = 3;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log("ENTERED!");
    if (other.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        canMelee = true;
        Enemy.Add (other.gameObject);
        for (int i = 0; i < Enemy.Count; i++)
        {
            ps.Add(Enemy[i].GetComponent<ParticleSystem>());
            EnemyScript.Add(Enemy[i].GetComponent<EnemyFollow1>());
            stat.Add(EnemyScript[i].enemyData);
        }
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
    if (other.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        canMelee = false;       
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (Enemy[i] == other.gameObject) 
            {
                Enemy.RemoveAt(i);
                stat.RemoveAt(i);
                EnemyScript.RemoveAt(i);
                ps.RemoveAt (i);
            }
        }
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if (canMelee && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q) && Time.time > AttackCooldownT && Enemy.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Enemy.Count; i++)
        {
            stat[i].HP -= 20;
            ps [i].Play ();
        }
        AttackCooldownT = Time.time + AttackCooldownTI;
    }
}
}
```

I created list of some objects(enemys) with some data list which I made with unity's scriptable objects. This script adds and removes enemys and
this script works fine but when there are 2 enemy many enemy's(same game object starts adding multiple times) and when it comes to removing all data doesn't gets removed so even if I killed an enemy, he's still in the scene.

My ItemData:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu]
public class StatData : ScriptableObject {

    public string Name;
    public bool Boss;
    public int HP, MaxHP, Atk, MaxAtk, SpAtk, MaxSpAtk, Def, MaxDef, SpDef, MaxSpDef;
    public Sprite sprite;
}
```

Also when I try to kill an enemy with same stat data both enemies die together while I only attack one. As the health is global both die. I can't figure out how to fix it.

In my enemy follow I wrote:

```
enemyStat.HP = enemyStat.MaxHP;
```

To have enemy alive in a new game.
Please help!

Comment: The phrase "when I try to kill an enemy with same stat data both enemies die together while I only attack one" indicates that you may have copied a reference to an object rather than create a new copy of that object. So your list contains two references to the same object.

Comment: I would like to help you, however I notice you have some other questions that clearly have an answer, but you have not accepted them as the answer.

Comment: Richardissimo I trend but didn't worked. Should I make a public float health ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This is an example of the [parallel collections anti-pattern](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/):

```
Enemy.RemoveAt(i);
stat.RemoveAt(i);
EnemyScript.RemoveAt(i);
ps.RemoveAt (i);
```

You should refrain from doing this, as it creates dependencies in your arrays that is not enforced by anything. For example, if you try to sort one of the arrays, you'll break the relationship between the indices.

You should create a "wrapper" object that binds these different objects together, then have a single list.

```
class EnemyCollator {
    public GameObject go;
    public EnemyFollow1 script;
    public StatData stats;
    public ParticleSystem particles;
}
...
public List<EnemyCollator> allEnemies;
```

If you want your data to have a look-up relationship (i.e. "find me the data associated with this GameObject"), use a dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<GameObject,EnemyCollator> dataLookup;
```

Or use a Linq query:

```
GameObject go = allEnemies.Find(x => x.go == someGameObject);
```

Once you start organizing your code this way, it is likely that the problem you have will go away.

Comment: @GamingForever Don't forget to upvote any post you found helpful as well as mark an answer as "accepted" (which one is your choice; on SO that's generally the one treated as "most correct").

Answer (score 0):

It is quite difficult to understand & read your code.

However i do notice some things that might help you.

When you create a scriptableobject and assign it to multiple other scripts/ gameobjects, they will all reference the same scriptableobject. So changing health will change the health reference for all objects calling it.

There are a few ways around this, but i think the simplest to implement for you is this:

Assign the variables from StatData to your Enemyscript when you instantiate it (or in it's Awake)

```
public class EnemyFollow1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string Name;
    public bool Boss;
    public int HP, MaxHP, Atk, MaxAtk, SpAtk, MaxSpAtk, Def, MaxDef, SpDef, MaxSpDef;
    public Sprite sprite;

    [SerializeField]
    private StatData statData;

    void Awake()
    {
        Name = statData.Name;
        Boss = StatData.Boss;
        // Etc...
    }
}
```

Now you are always sure that the health of the right enemy is modified. 
You can also call this script using the List of Gameobjects you have So you dont need "List of EnemyFollow1.

```
Enemy[i].GetComponentInChildren<EnemyFollow1>().HP -= 20;

// You can remove these
public List<EnemyFollow1> EnemyScript =  new List<EnemyFollow1>();
public List<StatData> stat = new List<StatData> ();
```

Also im not sure if you understand this. But removing a GameObject from a list, does not destroy it! 
So if you want to destroy a gameobject ***after*** removing it from a list, use

```
Destroy(Enemy[i]);
```

Comment: Somehow somewhere something is destroying/ disabling your gameobjects. I would have to see your other scripts, because gameobjects do not destroy automagically.

Comment: I actually destroyed it in another script so it isn't the problem.